# Firebase swift retrieve email with uid

Tags: swift, firebase, uid, firebasesimplelogin

Hello i have just started playing with firebase. My problem here is that i want to only print the current users email. Not everything that comes with it....

This is what the print block looks like:

```
[email: test@gmail.com, isTemporaryPassword: 0, profileImageURL: https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/1aedb8d9dc4751e229a335e371db8058?d=retro]
Optional(Secret code)
```

And this is how i print it:

```
print(CURRENT_USER.authData.providerData)
```

This is where i save the user:

```
var CURRENT_USER: Firebase
{
    let userID = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey("uid") as! String

    let currentUser = Firebase(url: "\(FIREBASE_REF)").childByAppendingPath("users").childByAppendingPath(userID)

    return currentUser
}
```

code
https://gyazo.com/20b2dcd0ddd7c7f8c61858ca1d653e3b

firebase users
https://gyazo.com/ce4516ef9a6ebf6963a9a1a43807158d

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
print(CURRENT_USER.authData.providerData["email"] as! String)
```

I have tried and it worked for me. It will print the current user email.

Answer (score 5):

For swift 4

```
let userEmail = Auth.auth().currentUser?.email
```